# Python numpy convert dtype object to dtype float32 in case of a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given this code:

```py
arr = np.array(
    [
        [
            np.array([1, 2, 3]),
            np.array([4, 9])
        ],
        [
            np.array([1, 2, 5]),
            np.array([5, 6])
        ],
        [
            np.array([1, 2, 5]),
            np.array([85, 86])
        ]
    ]
)

(input, expected) = arr.T

input[:2]
```

I am getting this output:

```
array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 5])], dtype=object)
```

But I want this to be a 2d array of type `dtype` `float32`.

So if I create it using a different way:

```py
np.array(
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 5]
    ], dtype=np.float32
)
```

This is what I want the output to look like:

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 5.]], dtype=float32)
```

How do I convert `input` into this 2d array, so I won't see `dtype=object`, but `dtype=float32`?

I've tried this:

```py
np.array(input[:2], dtype=np.float32)
```

but it prints this error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I've also looked at other functions like `view`, `asarray`, all of them resulted in a similar error.

Comment: Your `arr` is a (3,2) shaped object dtype array.  The element arrays differ in shape, as newer verisons should warn you.  Your `input` is a 1d array of objects.  Methods like `astype` or `reshape` don't reach across the dtype boundary.  You have to in some way or other convert it back to a list of arrays, and then apply the `np.array`.

Answer (score 0):

I found it eventually:

This doesn't work:

```py
np.array(input, dtype=np.float32)
```

But copying it does:

```py
np.array([x for x in input], dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: Equivalently `np.array(list(input))`, or `np.array(input.tolist()))` or even `np.stack(input)`.